# Android how to get path of mediastore?

Tags: android, path, mediastore

I'm trying to get the path were android save the images. With this code:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), myImage, "Title","Description").toString();
```

I get the path of the image that  `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1405408110218.jpg` but I want only the path of the folder like `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`. Please don't tell me to use split and join because it's not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Uri path = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

Or this:

```
Uri path = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```